# Find missing number in cyclical array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays that I need to compare and find the missing number using Javascript or jQuery. Finding *all* missing numbers is relatively easy but I need to treat the first array as if it were cyclical so that I only find the single missing number between the given numbers in the second array.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
var unsorted = [13,12,1,3]
```

How can I compare the two arrays and return the missing number 2, *without also returning 4-11*?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit with more information.** It's possible that comparing two arrays is the wrong way to do this. Here is my current code:

```
// Function: Put numbers in order and return missing number from sequence
// Possible numbers are 1 through 13 max

var cyclical = [13,12,1,3] 
// Other examples, always only four numbers: [13,12,11,2] 1 is missing, [11,12,2,13] 1 is missing

var nonCyclical = [3,1,5,4]
// Another example: [7,3,5,4] 6 is missing

function absent(arr) {
    var mia = [],
        min = Math.min.apply('', arr),
        max = Math.max.apply('', arr);
    while (min < max) {
        if (arr.indexOf(++min) == -1) mia.push(min);
    }
    return mia;
}

var missingNumCyclical = absent(cyclical);
// Result: 2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

var missingNum = absent(nonCyclical);
// Result: 2 (This is the desired result.)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Define *" between the given numbers"* and show expected results along with your attempts to solve this yourself. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"homework"* service. The objective is for people to help you fix **your code** not do all the work for you

Comment: Understood (first post blues). I've added extra info to help define the problem, and where I'm at.

Comment: What happens, when there are multiple equal length missing parts? For example cyclical = [9, 10, 11, 3, 4]

Comment: Idea - go over your numbers array, if element is missing in second array, add this to missing elements array of arrays position 0 (aka ma[0]). When element exists in second array, increment position in ma by 1. After that you have missing elements "by gaps". Then check, if ma first and last elements are cyclic (first element first is numbers first and last of last is numbers last), if yes, merge last to first and remove last. Then remove longest array in ma, as this is the cycle gap. Then merge rest of the ma - this is your result :) If needed, I can write this down in js tomorrow.

Comment: Rauli, regarding your first question: That shouldn't be possible because the numbers are 1 through 13 and there will always only be four numbers in the array. I just added clarification into the post for that.

Your second idea is interesting and could work if I understand it correctly. If you're able to create an example tomorrow, that would be super helpful. In the meantime, I will give it a shot, too. Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13].sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : - 1)
var list2 = [13,12,1,3]
  // Sort the list
  .sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : - 1)
  .map((v, i, a) => {
    // Create a clone since shift is mutative
    const clone = [...list1]
    // Shift the array to the position of "v"
    clone.shift(clone.indexOf(v))
    // Slice the array to the position of v + 1
    const result = clone.slice(0, clone.indexOf(a[i + 1]))

    if (result.length === 1) {
      return result[0]
    }

    return undefined
  })
  .filter(n => n != null)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does appear to find the number 2 in this exact example but if you change list2 to [13,12,2,3], then it should find the missing number 1, correct? It does not appear to do that. It's still displaying 2 as the result. Any ideas?